# Magento Grid ->addColumn string length

Tags: magento-1.9, grid, customer-grid

I'm trying to display Customer initials instead of full names in the Customer Grid.
ie.
Instead of "Mr John Middle Smith" I would like "Mr J M Smith"

Can anyone point me in the right direction to change this:

```
    $this->addColumn('firstname', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('First Name'),
        'index'     => 'firstname',
    ));
```

To just get the first character of `firstname`

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your own renderer for this.  See the example:

```
$this->addColumn('firstname', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('First Name'),
        'renderer'  => 'amexample/adminhtml_customer_grid_renderer_name',
         ....
    ));
```

The renderer class:

```
class Amasty_Example_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Grid_Renderer_Name extends  Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        return substr($row->getFirstname(), 0, 1);
    }
}
```

you can find default rendereres here:
app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer

Comment: Thanks, I've done this but when I try to run a CSV export I get the following error: Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /.../Renderer/FirstName.php, line 1

Comment: Please check that the file has no spaces before `<?php` tag

Comment: Nope, no spaces before the PHP tag :(

Comment: I'm still having problems with this: Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Renderer/Name.php, line 1 - any idea what would cause it? :(

Comment: can you please update your answer and post the whole file (may be as an attachment or link to download?)

Comment: Is it possible to do this without using the separate renderer file? As that's what is causing the issue on the export.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:** You have to override the file in local folder or just copy `app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Customer\Grid.php` to `app\code\local\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Customer\Grid.php`

**Step 2:** Replace below code with

```
    $this->addColumn('name', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Name'),
        'index'     => 'name'
    ));
```

Replace by

```
     $this->addColumn('namewithprifx', array(
       'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('First Name'),
        'index'     => 'firstname',
        'type'  => 'text',      
        'width' => '250px',
        'sortable'  =>false,
        'filter' => false,                                         
        'renderer' => 'NameSpace_Customergrid_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Namewithprifx',          
        ));
```

**Step 3:** Create file in `NameSpace\Customergrid\Block\Adminhtml\Renderer\Namewithprifx.php`

**Step 4:** Copy below code.

```
 <?php
 class NameSpace_Customergrid_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Namewithprifx extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
 {
   public function render(Varien_Object $row)
   {

    //$getData = $row->getData();               
    $str=$row->getData('prefix'). " ". $row->getData('fname'). " ". $row->getData('lname');
    return $str;
  }
}
```

**Step 5:** Refresh cache and check the data.

Comment: I have the same problem with your code as I do below: Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /.../Renderer/FirstName.php, line 1

Comment: I think check the render file path problem

Comment: What should the Render filer path be?
I originally had it here: app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Renderer

Comment: The code works - It only errors when running an Export

Comment: whar error you got?

Comment: There is no link with Export but Make sure when you press Export Button the Controller is calling or not

Comment: The error is: Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /.../Renderer/FirstName.php, line 1

Comment: for that I need to look into code.

Comment: do you need that field in CSV file? if not then I have code for that

Comment: Yes, I've added the column to the grid which works. I need the same data in the CSV file

Comment: give me some more time to figure out this problem

Comment: but you can make  answer as right

Comment: Any idea on the CSV export?

Comment: still not found ........

Comment: I have try in my pc It will working in export just make sure that you have remove unnecessary space form that

Comment: Strange. Can you ZIP up what you've done and upload it somewhere? Definitely no spaces before my PHP tag :(

Comment: No problem. Thank you for all of your help :-)